# How can I schedule a job in Sql Agent (Sql Server 2005) via C# code?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, scheduled-tasks

Hi I'd like to schedule an existing job in the Sql Server 2005 agent via C# code... i.e. when someone clicks a button on an asp.net web page.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: hi , have you succeeded in the end ? can you paste a code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here:  [SMO Job Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.job.aspx)

The [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc285859.aspx) lets you do practically anything programmatically in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186273(SQL.90).aspx

Covers both SMO and T-SQL methods.